# How to tell angular not to update view

Tags: angular, forms, accordion

Let's say I have this code :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;">
    // other stuff
</ng-container>
```

As soon as my `items` changes angular resets the view inside `<ng-container>`.
The region inside has accordions which has forms inside. 
So when any of the forms are updated the accordion sections get closed and this is not a desirable feature.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need avoid loop over a variable that can change. I don't know about your code, but in general you always can do

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let foo of count;let i=index">
    // other stuff but you use
    items[i]
</ng-container>
```

where you has a variable

```
count:any[];
```

And remember that, when you change the length of item you need write

```
this.count = new Array(items.length);
```

If you don't worry about when you change the items length you can create the array "on-fly" using repeat and split functions of string:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let foo of ' '.repeat(items.length).split('');let i=index">
    // other stuff but you use
    items[i]
</ng-container>
```

Other way is create a directive repeat

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[repeat]'
})
export class RepeatDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() set repeat(times: number) {
    let count=this.viewContainer.length;
    for (let i=this.viewContainer.length;i>times;i--)
      this.viewContainer.remove(i-1);

    for (let i = count ; i < times ; i++) 
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef,
      {
        $implicit:i
      });

  }
}
```

And use

```
<ng-container *repeat="items.length;let i">
..use item[i]...
</ng-container>
```