# Input field loses focus on typing when change event is emitted

Tags: angular

Within my app there are some input fields, which are sourced out into a ui specific component. This approach stretches over roughly two abstraction layers and if an change event occured, an action is triggered at the top layer.

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-ui-first-child
  (settingValueChanged)="facade.changeValue($event.Id, $event.value)"
</app-ui-first-child>
```

**first-child.component.html**

```
<div class="settings">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let category of settings">
    <landing-page-ui-preferences-app-category
      [settings]="category.settingSpecs"
      (settingValueChanged)="settingValueChanged.emit($event)">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**second-child.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let setting of settings; let i = index; trackBy: trackId">
  <div
    class="setting"
    [ngSwitch]="setting.style">
    <app-input
      *ngSwitchDefault
      [value]="setting.value ? setting.value : ''"
      (changedValue)="settingValueChanged.emit({ settingSpecId: setting.id, value: $event })"></app-input>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

My problem is, that if I'm typing into the input fields, an action gets triggered, but in the same moment, the input field looses focus and I have to click it again to continue typing.

Comment: Wouldn't you mind to reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: I think that it's the same problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830317/how-to-tell-angular-not-to-update-view/57832508#57832508. It's difficult know it exactly. BTW if you received as `@Input` an object, you needn't use a `@Output` if you only want to change the value of one property of the object -you can change in child or in parent because the object is the same-